# emit signal if cell of QTableView is clicked

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtableview

`QTableWidget` has a Method `cellClicked` which emits a Signal if a cell is been clicked

 
Im looking for a equal method for `QTableView`

there is a old post on the Qt Forum 
[How-to-select-a-cell-in-a-QTableView](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11723-How-to-select-a-cell-in-a-QTableView)

the suggestion there was to use `QItemSelectionModel` which is accessible via ``QAbstractItemView::selectionModel().`

the selection of the cell should work but `QItemSelectionModel` has no Signals that could be emmited if the cells is beeing clicked.
Is there a counterpart to emmit a Signal if a cell of a QTable View has been clicked ?

Comment: Which exact behavior do you need? Usually one would use selectionChanged (), not the same as"clicked" though.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld  yes selectionChanged ()  would fit better  after readig about it